# Line split / delimiter on an empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a single cell that contains this information.

```
+---------+
| ghijkl  | 
| aededd  |
|         |
| ededed  |
| ededfe  | 
|         |
| efefeef |
| efefeff |
+---------+
```

Can I split this into three cells?

```
+---------+ ---------+ ---------+  
| ghijkl  |  ededed  |  efefeef |
| aededd  |  ededfe  |  efefeff |
|         |          |          |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I tried the delimiter tool and various VBA code. All split at each single line break. None split on an empty line break/row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below sub-

```
Sub CellSplit()
Dim MyInput As String
Dim TempText As String, result As String
Dim sSplit

MyInput = Range("A1")
TempText = Replace(MyInput, Chr(10), "@")

sSplit = Split(TempText, "@@")

For i = LBound(sSplit) To UBound(sSplit)
    Cells(1, i + 2) = Replace(sSplit(i), "@", Chr(10))
Next i

End Sub
```

> ***Edit:*** To loop through over column use below sub.

```
Sub CellSplit()
Dim TempText As String
Dim sSplit
Dim cel As Range
Dim lRow As Long

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cel In Range("A1:A" & lRow)
    TempText = Replace(cel, Chr(10) & Chr(10), "@")
    sSplit = Split(TempText, "@")
        For i = LBound(sSplit) To UBound(sSplit)
            cel.Offset(0, i + 2) = sSplit(i)
        Next i
    Next cel
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know how I can loop this code to run down the column?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, it is working great!

Comment: @ESACAWIP Check simplified codes now. If you found the answer useful please mark it as answered (Tick mark it) so that visitors can understand your issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

The formula below will do the job.

```
=FILTERXML("<data><a>"&SUBSTITUTE($B2,CHAR(10)&CHAR(10),"</a><a>")&"</a></data>","/data/a["&COLUMN()-3&"]")
```

The original data are in B2. The *-3* must be 1 less than the number of the column in which you place the formula. For example, column E is the 5th column, meaning column 5. If you place the formula in column E the number in the formula must be -4.

Once you paste the formula to one cell and adjust the column indicator you can copy the formula to the right and it will display the 3 (or more) different texts without further adjustment.